# Xpath syntax to extract content from child node if other child has a specific value?

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract the "Blue" text from the paragraph tag in this HTML block but only if the h2 tag is == to "Foo".

How can I write a Xpath statement that will return the content of p by checking for the content of h2?

```
<section class="panel">
          <header class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="h5 mrgn-tp-0 mrgn-bttm-0">
              Foo color
            </h2>
          </header>
          <div class="panel-body">

              <p class="mrgn-bttm-0">
                  Blue
                  <br />
```

Thank you!

Comment: I should have specified that I want the h2 tag to Contain the "Foo" word instead of being equal to it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer! Code bellow works just fine if ever it can help anyone!

```
//section[@class = "panel"]//h2[contains(text(), "Foo")]/../following-sibling::div/p/text()
```

Comment: Be careful with absolute XPaths in predicates, like `[//h2]`, it's virtually always safer to use a relative XPath, ie. `[.//h2[contains.....]]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! @paul!